# How to specify one widget to center_horizontal while another widget 100dp away from it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Im trying to make two tab widgets in the center of an LinearLayout, and one Imageview 100 dp away from it. 
[image]

However, the `center_horizontal`  does not work.
[image]

if I add `gravity:center_horizonal` to its parent linearlayout, it center at the middle of two tabs and the imageview

[image]

I wonder if there's a way to center at the tabs while the imageview 100 dp away from it, while they keep align horizontally.

```
Edit***************************************
```

after I used relative layout:

[image]

**Edit Again  ,after add `alignParentRight`*********************

[image]

Comment: how about using a relative layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with `LinearLayout`. As @mattfred mentioned, use `RelativeLayout` instead:

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_border"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@android:id/tabs"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_title_btn_treehole_message_normal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks Gennadii, it works! , but i have one more question, for example, if i want to set the ImageView not margin_left but margin_right, will it coordinate imageview according to the relativelayout? i tried but seems like it did not work

Comment: sorry, I don't get that.. you want to set a right margin from relative layout's border? You can use paddingRight on a relative layout to achieve that

Comment: yes, i want to set the imageview like 100dp from the right border of the relativelayout, instead of the left widget-TabWidgets

Comment: looking at your screenshot there is plenty of space on the right of imageview.. Can you please 'draw' the expected result? maybe that will help me to understand..

Comment: oh, I think I understand.. try android:layout_alignParentRight="true" and android:layout_marginRight="100dp" on ImageView

Comment: hi Gennadii, I tried , but something strange happend after adding the align_ParentRight, please check my update.. ;)

Comment: try removing android:layout_toRightOf="@android:id/tabs"